# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

```
void FrameGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NamePersons.Clear();
            NamePersons.Add("");

            //Get the current frame form capture device
            currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

            //Convert it to Grayscale
            gray = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

            //Face Detector
            MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
          face,
          1.4,
          4,
          Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
          new Size(20, 20));

            //Action for each element detected
            foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
            {
                t = t + 1;
                result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);


                //if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
                //{
                    //TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained images like maxIteration
                    MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

                    //Eigen face recognizer
                    EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
                       trainingImages.ToArray(),
                       labels.ToArray(),
                       5000,
                       ref termCrit);
                    name = recognizer.Recognize(result);
                    groupBox1.Visible = true;
                    label12.Text = name.Trim();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from visitortb where name='"+name.Trim()+"'",db.Connect());
                    SqlDataReader dr;
                    dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        label13.Text = dr[5].ToString().Trim(); 
                        label14.Text = dr[10].ToString().Trim();
                        label16.Text = dr[7].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    //idcrd.showIDCard(name);
                    //Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
                    currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));

                }

            NamePersons[t - 1] = name;
            NamePersons.Add("");

           // }
            t = 0;

            //Names concatenation of persons recognized
            //for (int nnn = 0; nnn < facesDetected[0].Length; nnn++)
            //{
            //    //names = names + NamePersons[nnn] + ", ";
            //}
            ////Show the faces procesed and recognized
            //imageBoxFrameGrabber.Image = currentFrame;
            ////label4.Text = names;
            //names = "";
            ////Clear the list(vector) of names
            //NamePersons.Clear();

        }
```

Trying to get the details of the faces detected from the database, but I have been getting this error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index" at the line

```
NamePersons[t - 1] = name;
```

Comment: Do you allow `t == 0`? That'd be a start.

Comment: Where is t declared?  Regardless, you might want to step around the code in a debugger, keeping track of the value of t and the number of items stored in NamePersons.  That will almost certainly show you where your error of logic is.

Comment: @BobbyDigital do you mean I have to write a condition for t==0 ?

Comment: Yes, if `t == 0` `[t-1] == -1` conflicting with "Must be non-negative and ...".

Comment: I think @BobbyDigital is pointing out that when t is zero, the call to the indexer will fail.  It seems that the minimum value of t there is 1, so my guess is that t - 1 is too big rather than too small.  It's a little confusing, though, with the adding of the empty strings (why do you do that?) which is why I suggested the debugger.

Comment: @phoog t is declared globally,but it isn't initialized any value,and the code I have posted above is just the definition.So do I have to initialize t ?

Comment: @BobbyDigital no,I haven't wrote any condition that allows t==0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You commented out an if block but you commented out the wrong closing brace.  Because of that, these lines appear *after* the foreach block, when they originally were inside it:

```
NamePersons[t - 1] = name;
NamePersons.Add("");
```

You increment t inside the foreach block, so if `facesDetected` is empty, then t will be zero and you'll get the index out of range exception.

If you had stepped through your code in the debugger, you would have found that problem in about 2 minutes instead of an hour.

Another comment:

By "declare t globally" do you mean that it is a field of the class?  That is almost certainly a poor design decision.  If the variable is used only locally in the method, it should be declared as a local variable of the method.